# Double footer issue in IE9 only

Tags: internet-explorer-9, double, footer

I'm having an issue where the footer shows up twice but only in IE9. (IE8 & 10, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, all display correctly)

The url is http://hartconsultingservices.com/craigdickens/

Is there a way for it to force the rending in another version of IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using this Javascript code you can check if the browser is internet explorer, and get the version number, if they match the one that gives you a problem, you can alter the footer div from the javascript.
An alternate way would be to leave the footer div blank in your CSS, and add the CSS in javascript using Jquery, however, if you are not already using Jquery, this might be overkill to download such a huge library.

```
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName;
var fullVersion;
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var veroffset;

// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
```

taken from: [JavaScripter](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browsern.htm)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply :)  I'm not too familiar with javascript... where would i place this piece of coding?

Comment: You put this within the '<script></script>' tags in the html, its probably a good idea for you to follow [this](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/) tutorial, which will also explain changing the CSS elements from javascript.